# Can an 'AGA' oven be koshered?

Tags: halacha, technology, appliances, kashering-kosherization

Can an 'AGA oven' be koshered?

Here are [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGA_cooker) and [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxRp9b1yFGA) explanations of what an AGA oven is. Here's an excerpt from the Wikipedia page:

> The **AGA cooker** is a heat storage stove and cooker, which works on the
>   principle that a heavy frame made from cast iron components can absorb
>   heat from a relatively low-intensity but continuously-burning source,
>   and the accumulated heat can then be used when needed for cooking.

Comment: kiri, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please note that any advice you see here should be treated as if it came from a crowd of your friends, and all final decisions should be made by your local Rabbi. (-breath-) I look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: You could improve this question by adding more detail about what you know about AGA ovens that makes you wonder about whether they can be koshered.

Answer (score 4):

From investigating AGA ovens, in theory there is no problem in kashering them.

In practice it's gonna be quite complex. They have a ton of areas, and they are massive with a lot of thermal mass.

In order to kasher them, you have to heat them up quite hot, but because of the thermal mass it's going to take a huge amount of energy and a very large flame. It may be impossible to do it with a regular torch.

For a final answer you should ask your Rabbi about it - but I *strongly* recommend that you insist he see the oven in person, since it's not a typical oven.

Also, as a practical note AGA ovens are EXTREMELY energy inefficient. Very wasteful, I would not recommend them.